# How to add Mobx observer to LitElement

Tags: mobx, lit-element

I have the following component, my component correctly displays the message from appState but when I change the value of appState the component isn't updated. I know I need to add an @observer, but how do you add it to a LitElement?

```
import { LitElement, html } from 'lit-element';
import { observable } from "mobx";

var appState = observable({
  message: 'World'
});

class MyElement extends LitElement {

  handleClick() {
    appState.message = 'All';
  }

  render(){
    return html`
      <p>Hello, ${appState.message}</p>
      <button @click=${this.handleClick}>Click me</button>
    `;
  }
}

customElements.define('my-element', MyElement);
```

Answer (score 2):

LitElement itself is not such a good fit for mobx as changes which trigger a render need to be "full changes". Changing a property of an object is still the same object instance e.g. it will not trigger a render.

You can read the full story at https://open-wc.org/faq/rerender.html

You probably could use mobx autorun to trigger `this.updateComplete()` to force rerender but in that case, it's probably better to use a specialised lit-element version like https://github.com/adobe/lit-mobx.

Alternatively, a state machine could be a good fit in many cases as well. Take a look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/lit-robot.